# While working with hyperledger fabric, "./createPeerAdminCard.sh" command not working. Composer version issue prompts up

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

While using the command - "./createPeerAdminCard.sh" , the following message is shown.

Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv12
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Cannot use Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required

Comment: Check your `composer --version`.

Answer (score 1):

" @package_branch_alias_version@ (**1.0.0-beta2**) 2016-03-27 16:00:34 "

This doesn't look like a version number for Hyperledger Composer.  I wonder if you have some other software installed called composer?

You can try `which composer` which will show you the location of the composer you are using which might help, and you could also try `npm ls -g --depth=0` to see what npm packages you have installed - this will show what version of Hyperledger Composer you have, and any other possible 'composer' installed by npm.

Assuming you find the 'rogue' composer you can uninstall that then install the correct composer as suggested by @emiliomarin

Comment: Composer has be deprecated for quite a while now, I would recommend finding an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest Composer version:

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
```